# React.js not serving stream package to FE => cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') at Hash.CipherBase (index.js:7:1)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package, stream

Full error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
    at Hash.CipherBase (index.js:7:1)
    at new Hash (browser.js:9:1)
    at Object.createHash (browser.js:29:1)
    at browser.js:60:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at sha512 (browser.js:59:1)
    at browser.js:223:1
    at async encryptWithPublicKey (SellerCreateProductPage.js:109:1)
```

At this pint in the code:

```
let data = await EthCrypto.encryptWithPublicKey(pk,pk);
```

(I am trying to encrypt the public key with itself)

I am trying to use module "eth-crypto" in my React.js app. First when I imported it I got error saying webpack 5.0 doesn't serve packages such as crypto and stream to the front end. I fixed this issue by creating this `config.override.js` file:

```
const { ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (config, env) {
    return {
        ...config,
        module: {
            ...config.module,
            rules: [
                ...config.module.rules,
                {
                    test: /.(m?js|ts|tsx)$/,
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    use: ['source-map-loader'],
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            ...config.plugins,
            new ProvidePlugin({
                process: 'process/browser',
                Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            ...config.resolve,
            fallback: {
                "stream": require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
                "crypto": require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            },
        },
        ignoreWarnings: [/Failed to parse source map/],
    };
};
```

And updated the `package.json` scripts to run with react-app-rewired:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

I suspect it is problem with the 'stream' package, but i can't find a way to properly serve it to the front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Had to:

1. remove node_modules
2. remove "stream" fron package.json
3. run `npm install`
4. run `npm install readable-stream`
5. update the `config-overrides.js`:

- change `"stream": require.resolve('stream-browserify'),`
  to `"stream": require.resolve('readable-stream'),`

6. restart the react app